# C++: Pass variable from function outside main into function call inside main

Tags: c++

This is a little coin flip program I'm working on. I'm trying to pass a variable from function **promptUser();** to **flipCoin();**. I know you can create a local variable inside main function, but i'd like to organize prompts into functions.

Is there a way to pass the **flipCount** value from the **promptUser();** function to the **flipCoin();** function?

I've spent some time on google looking for a way to do this (if there's a way), but I don't think I am able to express what I am trying to do correctly, or this just isn't the way it's done. However, if anybody understands what I'm trying to achieve, or why I shouldn't do it this way, I would appreciate the advice. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

// function prototype
void promptUser();
void flipCoin(time_t seconds);

// prefix standard library
using namespace std;

const int HEADS  = 2;
const int TAILS = 1;

int main(){

    time_t seconds;
    time(&seconds);
    srand((unsigned int) seconds);

    promptUser();
    flipCoin(seconds);
    return 0;
}

void promptUser(){
    int flipCount;
    cout << "Enter flip count: " << endl;
    cin >> flipCount;
}

void flipCoin(time_t seconds){
    for (int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
        cout << rand() % (HEADS - TAILS + 1) + TAILS << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to store the variable somewhere so the options you have are: a) have a global variable to store flipCount - which is generally a bad idea; b) have a local variable in main - which you don't want; c) make `promptUser()` return an int and pass it as a parameter to `flipCoin()`, e.g. `flipCoin( promptUser );`.

Comment: Is option c) more practical than option b)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply return `flipCount` back to `main` and then let `main` pass it as an argument to `flipCoin`.

```
int main() {
  // ...
  // Get the flip count from the user
  int flipCount = promptUser();
  // Flip the coin that many times
  flipCoin(seconds, flipCount);
  // ...
}

int promptUser() {
  int flipCount;
  cout "Enter flip count: " << endl;
  cin >> flipCount;
  // Return the result of prompting the user back to main
  return flipCount;
}

void flipCoin(time_t seconds, int flipCount) {
  // ...
}
```

Think of `main` as being in charge. First `main` orders "Prompt the user for the number of flips!" and the `promptUser` function does as it's told, giving the number of flips back to main. Then `main` says "Now I know how many the flips the user wants... so flip the coin that many times!" passing that number to `flipCoin` to carry out the job.

```
main              promptUser      flipCoin
  |                   :               :
  |------------------>|               :
    "How many flips?" |               :
                      |               :
  |<------------------|               :
  |         3         :               :
  |                   :               :
  |---------------------------------->|
        "Flip the coin 3 times!"      |
                      :               |
  |<----------------------------------|
  |        <void>     :               :
  V
 END
```

Comment: Thanks for sharpening my understanding, and for the diagram!

Answer (score 0):

You're using c++ so make a Flipper class that way you can abstract the flipCount from main entirely. This way you could completely change how the prompt and flipping work without main having to know at all.

```cpp
class Flipper {
public:
    Flipper();
    void promptUser();
    void flipCoin(time_t seconds);
private:
    // This stores the data outside of your main function.
    int flipCount_;
}

Flipper::Flipper()
: flipCount_(0) {}

void Flipper::promptUser() {
    cout << "Enter flip count: " << endl;
    cin >> flipCount_;
}

void Flipper::flipCoin(time_t seconds) {
    for (int i=0; i < flipCount_; i++) {
        cout << rand() % (HEADS - TAILS + 1) + TAILS << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    time_t seconds;
    time(&seconds);
    srand((unsigned int) seconds);

    Flipper flipper;  // Make a flipper
    flipper.promptUser(); // Prompt the user
    flipper.flipCoin(seconds); // Flip the coin
}
```